# Is there a way to take screenshots of current running Java desktop application and stream it as video?

Tags: java, swing, vnc

So I have a java desktop application running on a server.

I would like to take series of screenshot which can be streamed to the client.

It should be almost as if watching a VNC video output.

Basically need a way to stream the graphic output from java desktop application runing on the server to the client.

It would best if there was a tool to capture the region of the running application and stream that region as video to the client.

Comment: why don't you use a vncserver like http://www.tightvnc.com/ for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Cisco Webex](http://www.webex.com/) you can make that server a host of the presentation and then only share the window you need with other 'participants' of the presentation. Buy Webex costs money. I am sure that there is some VNC tool that can share only part of the desktop. Maybe [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/index.php)?

Comment: is there a flash video driver? looks like ultravnc has java viewer. it'd be nice if there was a flash video viewer.

Comment: @KimJongWoo I don't know. Honestly, it's just the first thing that popped in Google search ;)